# How to restremplate to deletemapping with requestbody of list of objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to connect an endpoint which is in other profile and it defined as following:

```
 @DeleteMapping("/persons")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> deletePersons(@RequestBody List<Persons> persons) {
```

I send a `resttemplate` as following but it does not work:

```
 public ResponseEntity<Boolean> deletePersons(List<Persons> persons) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
        HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>("persons", headers);

        return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, httpEntity, Boolean.class,
            persons);
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> No HttpMessageConverter for java.lang.String

Comment: Please show where/how you're initializing your `restTemplate` variable.

Comment: How would u define it using @qualifier?

Answer (score 0):

I think here you are getting back a String as response but you want to return a Boolean with your function, and it cant't convert the String to Boolean.

```
return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, httpEntity, Boolean.class,
            persons);
```

Comment: Then please give us more informations about the error. I don't think it says only that. Show us the whole message. Also what is the URL?

Comment: How would u define it plz?